# Deleting reoccurring strings contained in every line of a file

Tags: bash, file, unix

I have a file that looks like this:

```
[hello] - one
[hello] - two
[hello] - three
[hello] - four
```

I want to delete the '[hello] -' in every line so it will give me

```
one
two
three
four
```

Comment: What's the "algorithm": just print the last field? print from the 3rd field? delete `[hello] -`? Meaning, if you got a line "hello how are you", what would you need to print?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`cut <filename> -d" " -f3`

Answer (score 0):

I would go with `cut`, but here are some other options:

With `awk`:

```
$ awk -F' *- *' '{ print $NF }' << EOF
> [hello] - one
> [hello] - two
> [hello] - three
> [hello] - four
> EOF
one
two
three
four
```

With `sed`:

```
$ sed 's/^\[hello\] - //' << EOF
> [hello] - one
> [hello] - two
> [hello] - three
> [hello] - four
> EOF
one
two
three
four
```